# Fabric: Answers: purchase event

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I'm tracking purchase events in an iOS app with Answers (part of Fabric).

```
Answers.logPurchaseWithPrice(13.50,
                  currency: "USD",
                  success: true,
                  itemName: "Answers Shirt",
                  itemType: "Apparel",
                  itemId: "sku-350",
                  customAttributes: nil)
```

My use case envolves an order with multiple items, plus shipping for the whole order.

What would be the best way to track this in the Purchase event?

I'm thinking the safest bet it would be a single event with the total value.
But I wonder if I should trigger various purchase events, would this be graciously supported by answers?

Comment: Fabric is becoming obsolete by the end of this month. Check their site for further information.

Comment: Fabric is not becoming obsolete but will be migrate to Firebase, the events sill regulary happen. More [here](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap)

Comment: Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. Correct, Fabric's mobile apps only are going away Nov 30th. Fabric itself will remain through mid-2019, including Beta, Crashlytics and Answers. 

You can log multiple purchase events per session and that's a good way to handle multiple items being added to a cart.